# How to get the count of most frequent pattern in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to get the ten most frequent patterns in search with `elasticsearch` .
Example :

```
"cgn:4189, dfsdkfldslfs"
"cgn:4210, aezfvdsvgds"
"cgn:4189, fdsmpfjdjs"
"cgn:4195, cvsf"
"cgn:4189, mkpjd"
"cgn:4210, mfsfgkpjd"
```

I want to get :

```
4189 : 3
4210 : 2
4195 : 1
```

I know how to do that in `mysql` or via awk/sort/head ... but with `elasticsearch` I'm lost.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly how it will work depends on your analyzer, but if you are just using the default, [standard analyzer](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html), you can probably get what you want pretty easily with a [terms aggregation](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html).

As a simple example, I set up a trivial index:

```
PUT /test_index
{
   "settings": {
      "number_of_shards": 1
   }
}
```

Then indexed the data you posted, using the [bulk api](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html):

```
POST /test_index/doc/_bulk
{"index":{"_id":1}}
{"msg":"cgn:4189, dfsdkfldslfs"}
{"index":{"_id":2}}
{"msg":"cgn:4210, aezfvdsvgds"}
{"index":{"_id":3}}
{"msg":"cgn:4189, fdsmpfjdjs"}
{"index":{"_id":4}}
{"msg":"cgn:4195, cvsf"}
{"index":{"_id":5}}
{"msg":"cgn:4189, mkpjd"}
{"index":{"_id":6}}
{"msg":"cgn:4210, mfsfgkpjd"}
```

Then I can run a simple terms aggregation to get back all the terms and how often they occur (ordered descending by term frequency by default):

```
POST /test_index/_search?search_type=count
{
   "aggs": {
      "msg_terms": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "msg"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

which returns:

```
{
   "took": 4,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 6,
      "max_score": 0,
      "hits": []
   },
   "aggregations": {
      "msg_terms": {
         "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
         "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key": "cgn",
               "doc_count": 6
            },
            {
               "key": "4189",
               "doc_count": 3
            },
            {
               "key": "4210",
               "doc_count": 2
            },
            {
               "key": "4195",
               "doc_count": 1
            },
            {
               "key": "aezfvdsvgds",
               "doc_count": 1
            },
            {
               "key": "cvsf",
               "doc_count": 1
            },
            {
               "key": "dfsdkfldslfs",
               "doc_count": 1
            },
            {
               "key": "fdsmpfjdjs",
               "doc_count": 1
            },
            {
               "key": "mfsfgkpjd",
               "doc_count": 1
            },
            {
               "key": "mkpjd",
               "doc_count": 1
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Here is the code I used:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/a827095b675596c4e3d545ce963cde3fae932156